# One or more computer names are not valid when run powershell command in Active Directory CN

Tags: powershell, active-directory

So I am learning powershell and currently want to set the password on the local built in admin account. I can run the following command in an OU test group and it works.

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {net user administrator "R@nd0mP@ssw0rd!@#"} -ComputerName (Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "OU=Test,DC=fqdn,DC=local" -Filter * | Select-Object -Expand Name) *> "C:\users\user\desktop\WinRMAdminPWSet.txt"
```

If I run this command on our CN that contains our computers, I get the following error.

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {net user administrator "R@nd0mP@ssw0rd!"} -ComputerName (Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "CN=Computers,DC=fqdn,DC=local" -Filter * | Select-Object -Expand Name) *> "C:\users\user\desktop\WinRMAdminPWSet.txt"

Invoke-Command : One or more computer names are not valid. If you are trying to pass a URI, use the -ConnectionUri parameter, or pass URI objects instead of strings.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {net user administrator "R@nd0mP@ssw0rd! ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (System.String[]:String[]) [Invoke-Command], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionInvalidComputerName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

I feel like there shouldn't be a difference in running this command on and OU and CN, but it seems that way?

Comment: I would try checking what computer names are being returned as a sanity check:
 $computerNames = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "CN=Computers,DC=fqdn,DC=local" -Filter * | Select-Object -Expand Name

Write-Host "computer names are: $computerNames"

Comment: If you do only a Get-ADComputer with search base the container do you get the results? If so you can export the computer list and run foreach command to get the information you need.